# Why sometimes filereader onload doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(


    function(details)
    {
        k++;
        console.log('beforerequest',k)
        if(finish==false)
        {

        buffer=details.requestBody.raw[0].bytes     
        console.log('before')  
        var blob = new Blob([buffer]);
//将 Blob对象 读成字符串
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function (e) {
        var send=reader.result; //a Hello world!

        data[k]=send
        }
        reader.readAsText(blob, 'utf-8');
        console.log(k,"次")




        }

        //} 
    },
    {urls: ["https://mms.pinduoduo.com/sydney/api/goodsDataShow/queryGoodsSpanDateList"]},
    ['requestBody']
);
```

Sometimes the code doesn't work,the 'k' can't be printed correctely.I don't know why it happens.
It will works severl times,k is a counter,every time the code works,the k plus one.'k'should printed from 0 to nine,but it started from 1,the first one is jumped

Comment: What is `k`, where does it come from?

Comment: is this wrapped in a function or a while loop of some kind? Or is it only meant to run once?

Comment: It will works severl times,k is a counter,every time the  code works,the k plus one

Comment: If `raw[0].bytes` is empty there'll be an invalid blob so FileReader won't read it.

Comment: It is impossible that 'raw[0].bytes' is empty,I have printed that and try it

Comment: How did you verify it's not empty? Show the code.